# InDesign SDK : Can I use the SDK without installing InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

First, let me clarify the question.
I am dealing with InDesign documents and trying to extract information from it. I read it somewhere that Adobe InDesign loads the documents and dynamically calculates some metadata information that is not present in the .indd or .idml files.

For my use case, i need to write a software that loads an InDesign file and extracts all information from it - without any loss. Can this be done using Adobe's InDesign SDK, without actually having InDesign software installed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt if you can do that ->
There are many functions that fetch the INDD file information dynamically from the InDesign app itself. Such information is not a part of the InDesign file.

For IDML files, IDML files are just a view and not a model. They do not contain enough information to be used offline without the app. If your's is a minimal app and you only need certain information from the InDesign document, then it's fine otherwise IDML would not be of much help.

Comment: So, no IDML to be used. That's why I was confused, about usind app.functionNames offline since the info is fetched from the app! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to extract information from an IDML file instead of trying to get it from an `.indd` file directly. InDesign files are binary files whereas IDML files are packaged up XML making them *a lot* easier to parse.

You should be able to easily process a standalone IDML file using these resources as a guide:

[IDML Specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/cs55-docs/IDML/idml-specification.pdf)

[IDML Cookbook](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/cs5_docs/idml/idml-cookbook.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Josh. I had been working with IDML files for quite some time, but then I discovered that IDML files are dynamically rendered/loaded - They are a view and not a model. So, you cannot exactly figure out how a magazine/book would look when opened with InDesign.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help. Maybe you could elaborate more in your question what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: In IDML there are text frames that refer to stories. If there are threaded frames they all point to the same story.
What if you want to convert from IDML to any other file format. There is no way to figure out how much text fits into a text frame. 

So, if there are images to go with some text we lose the context when converting from IDML - you cannot figure out where exactly to place the image.

That's why i wanted to know, can we use the SDK in our project without having the InDesign software set up.

Comment: Sounds like a tough project I can't help you there. I do know that we've been using a plugin that converts Quark files to InDesign and even that plugin isn't perfect at handling reflow correctly. So, I won't say it's impossible, but very difficult.

Comment: Not a problem Josh! Trust me, I know it's a difficult project.
That's why I wanted to know if we can use the SDK offline, so that I don't have to deal with IDML anymore.

Comment: @divyanshm I have a project like your problem you said. Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but not via InDesign SDK, instead you will have to use a XMP library which can extract the information from the INDD file.

Note that this extraction will be limited to the information that exists in the form of XML in the INDD file that includes page previews and file Meta data.

You can download the XMP SDK from the following link: https://www.adobe.com/products/xmp.html

Note that if you want to access all data, you will need InDesign file exported in IDML format. This is zipped package that gives you all the data in XML format, just unpack the file and use any standard XML parser to play around.